# Reshow contents on page reload History.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I've been trying history.js and it works well. However, when I reload the page it says not found. Here is the code:

```
<body>
MAIN NAVIGATION
<a href="#" link="hello">hello page</a>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
    $("a").click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr("link");
        history.pushState(null, null, page)
        $("#mydiv").load(page + ".html");

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is that a section of your html file or is that the full code?
and are you trying to run this code while "MAIN NAVIGATION" is there?

Comment: Yes, the page that will be loaded will be inserted inside the #mydiv

Comment: Is that the entire history.js file?

Comment: Yes it is the entire js file

Comment: There is a lot of stuff wrong. Unless this was a react app, your html should not be in your js file, that must be in a separate html file. You are missing html tags and the closing tags to your body. You will also need to include Jquery otherwise $ will be undefined.

Comment: Its not that I will really combine them, I combined them only to  show it in an easy way